# java generics List<ActorRef> elements are not ActorRef

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have defined a list of subscribers

```
public class PropertyHandlerInfo<T> {
...
    public final List<ActorRef> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

when I want to retrieve an element of list I get an Object type not a ActorRef.

```
PropertyHandlerInfo propertyHandlerInfo = new PropertyHandlerInfo();
...
ActorRef o = propertyHandlerInfo.subscribers.get(0);
```

I get the floowing error:

Error:(34, 61) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to akka.actor.ActorRef

What can be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

This question asks a practical problem, some people showed me a similar theoretical question:

[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

I can extrapolate the answer to this question from that link.

The most helpful comment was for me:
"Using a raw type erases ALL generics in that class." by Jorn Vernee

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321

Comment: @azurefrog: same here.

Comment: There are many dupes of this, so I'll say it here: Using a raw type erases _ALL_ generics in that class.

Comment: That's it, what @JornVernee states.

Comment: This answer says what happens: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626695/7470253). Basically, since your type is generic and you ignored generic types on it, Java compiler chooses to wipe **all** generics-related information from your type-use.

Comment: @JornVernee: Thanks it is the solution.